# OS image with ssh enabled

Tags: pi-3, wifi, boot, pi-3b+

My Raspberry Pi appears to boot but there is no HDMI output.

I’ve tried various troubleshooting steps but with no success.

Before I go down the route of buying another Pi I was wondering if there’s an OS image out there which would install with SSH (or VNC) enabled and which I could configure to connect to my Wi-fi automatically after installation ?

Comment: Voted close as this is a normal process for headless images.  Look at headless boot option for ssh at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/README.md See options https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111425/is-there-a-way-to-set-up-a-raspberry-pi-without-a-keyboard-mouse-or-sd-card-re

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Raspbian Headlessly](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/109338/installing-raspbian-headlessly)

Answer (score 3):

just put an empty file named ssh in the boot folder and ssh will be automatically enabled

Answer (score 0):

For this, you will need access to your router:

1. Flash a normal RaspiOS 32-bit installation to the SD card.
2. Plug the drive into a computer and add a file named `ssh` or `ssh.txt` or `SSH.txt` (the file can be empty it doesn't matter) to the BOOT drive.
3. If you want a WiFi connection create another file wpa_supplicant.conf

   ```
   country=GB
   ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
   update_config=1
   network={
           ssid="Your WiFi SSID goes here"
           psk="Your WiFi password goes here"
   }
   ```

   Obviously change the SSID and password to your values. Change `Country=GB` to your local value.

   Or Connect the Pi to your router with an ethernet cable.
4. Power it on.
5. On your routers page search for the Pi and note down the IP address.

   Now on linux type: `ssh pi@youradress`. Or since the RPi is running mDNS try `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`

   On Windows download [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html) and connect to pi@192.168.xxx.xxx or pi@raspberrypi.local

Comment: in 999/1000 home setups ... `ssh raspberrypi.local` will work - so step 5 is probably not required :p - also, windows 10 HAS ssh already

Comment: Thank you.If I download an OS image to an SD card, won’t the installation require a keyboard/monitor connected to the Pi?